# .htaccess rewrite not rewriting url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to force do a url rewrite to protect my original photos and only show watermarked ones. I am very new with Apache coding. 
Here is my code I put in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^system/files/photos/(.*\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))$ /system/files/styles/watermark/private/photos/$1 [NC,QSA]
```

and its not working. I've tried adding a `R` flag as well, but that didn't help. What am I missing? I know that I have permissions for mod_rewrite in the .htaccess file because there are other rewrite rules being used.

EDIT:

I got it to work, I added a R and L flag in, and its blocked. However, I don't really understands why, if someone could explain, that would be great. (The url I was using was www.example.com/system/files/photos/[filename]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already fixed your problem.

> I added a R and L flag in, and its blocked. However, I don't really understands why, if someone could explain

The `[R]` flag indicates that if match is found it will redirect to the pattern specified. By default it will redirect with the status code (**302** Found)

While the `[L]` flag tells apache if rule matches, it stop processing further rules.